# What species or individuals can restore life?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-voyager, star-trek-tos

The two I can think of at the moment are Q and Nomad. Q's power is pretty much unlimited, and Nomad restored Scotty's life.

I guess maybe you could argue that Seven of Nine, or any Borg Drone, can also restore life, as Seven brought back Neelix from the dead.

Perhaps you could also include the Guardian of Forever or the Krenim as indirect restorers of life.

Comment: *Anyone* with the Genesis device.

Comment: I'm basing my answer on the assumption that you only want cases where it is demonstrated that these species have the ability to restore life.  If you want speculation, then this question would likely get closed as beeing 'too broad' or 'primarily opinion based'

Comment: I guess this is not what you mean, but, arguably, anybody who has the power to travel into the past has the power to prevent a death that has already occurred.

Comment: @PeregrineRook this is exactly the issue with counting time travelling as having this power, as the list would theoretically become endless!

Comment: I was more interested in species that can restore life "on the spot."

Comment: This question was more difficult to answer than I initially thought. I guess Spock was right when he said that as a matter of cosmic history, it has always been easier to destroy than to create.

Comment: As the Vulcans say: Kup-fun-tor ha'kiv na'ish du stau?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at a [list of resuscitations](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Death), we have a reasonable idea:

- Augments: in *Star Trek Into Darkness*, Khan's blood is used to bring Kirk back from the dead from radiation poisoning
- Nomad: resurrected Scotty in *TOS* 'The Changeling
- The caretaker of the planet in 'Shore Leave': McCoy was killed by a Knight's Lance, but then revived
- The Genesis Device: revived Spock's dead body in *Wrath of Khan*/*Search for Spock*
- Skilled Starfleet Doctors: on a number of cases, we see that a being that is dead for a short enough period can be revived using Starfleet medical technology (e.g. Crusher in *TNG* 'Code of Honour' revived the dead Yareena)
- The Kobali (*VOY* 'Ashes to Ashes')
- Species 149 (whose reanimation technology was used by the Borg to reanimate Neelix in *VOY* 'Mortal Coil)

It is never demonstrated that Q have this power, although the events of *TNG* 'Tapestry' and 'Hide and Q', it is reasonable to conclude that they too have this power.

Comment: @armadillo we could assume this, but I'm trying to limit this list to definite cases; once we get into the realm of speculation, this list could get very long and the question could be closed as 'too broad'

Comment: Riker, with Q powers, pretty much regrets not restoring the child's life in "Hide and Q." Even if that didn't occur, I think it's kind of silly to not include the Q.

Comment: @T-1000'sSon that is a fair point, so I'll include them

Comment: In the 3rd seasons TNG Episode _Transfigurations_ , "John Doe", who was on his way toward becoming a higher being, brought Worf back after he fell to his death with a broken neck.

Comment: Wasn't Worf officially dead in the episode when he had the spinal column replacement?  Can't remember the title off the top of my head.

Comment: @psubsee2003 "Ethics", and yes, it was clinical death (or at least insomuch as Crusher and the other doctor understood death at that point).

Answer (score 0):

Charlie x's alien adopters brought back the people he made "go away"...

Comment: Yes, the Thasians.

Answer (score -1):

To add to Often Right's spectacular list:  Didn't Kai Winn poison Gul Dukat as a sacrafice to the Pah Wraiths, but the Pah Wraiths were like "Nuh uh" and then Gul Dukat was like "Wazzup!" and then Kai Winn was all "Oh snap!"  So Pah Wraiths, too.

Comment: Um, is that English?